# SQLITE Insert statement with user input

Tags: python, sqlite, insert

Is there such thing as:

```
c.execute("INSERT INTO data(borrow, dateTimeIN) VALUES(1, ?)", datetime('now'), "WHERE ic = '?')", x)
```

Basically this statement inserts the borrow item and date, time when the specific user borrows the item.

Or

```
c.execute("INSERT INTO data(borrow, dateTimeIN) VALUES(1, 'datetime()') WHERE ic = ?", x)
```

Comment: You can use more `?` in SQL query to add more information to query.

Comment: @furas er, i dont understand

Comment: `VALUES(1, ?) WHERE ic = '?')", datetime('now'), x`

Comment: @furas i got TypeError: an integer is required (got type str) when i tried this.

Comment: because `datetime()` doesn't except `now` (but it wasn't part of question). There is `datetime.datetime.now()` or `datetime.datetime.today()` and `datetime.date.today()` But probably you will have to convert it to string using `.strftime(...)`. See http://strftime.org/

Comment: @furas i manage to use datetime.now() although i have to combine the date and time together now. tq! :)

Comment: @furas It is not necessary to use `strftime`, `now()` will be inserted as `2016-11-23 09:15:58.615744`.

Comment: @LutzHorn but OP may need different format - ie. only date, or 11/23/2016

Comment: @furas Maybe, maybe not. He does not tell us.

Comment: @LutzHorn yes Op not tell - but it seems OP knows nothing about datetime so I expect OP soon ask why query doesn't insert date ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`exectute`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite3.Cursor.execute) accepts parameters, but they follow the SQL template as a tuple.

```
c.execute("INSERT INTO data(borrow, dateTimeIN) VALUES(1, ?) WHERE ic = ?)",
  (datetime.datetime.now(), x))
```

The `?` placeholder must not be enclosed in quotes `'`, `execute` will take care of putting them around the value of the string parameter `x`.

**Edit:**

But still your SQL will not work because [`INSERT`](https://sqlite.org/lang_insert.html) does not support a `where` clause, at least when `values` are given.

```
sqlite3.OperationalError: near "where": syntax error
```

Comment: if i change to `UPDATE` Statement? 
to `c.execute("UPDATE data SET(borrow=1, dateTimeIN=?) WHERE ic=?", (dt, (x,)))`??? i am facing sqlite3.OperationalError: near "(": syntax error

Comment: Read the [`UPDATE`](https://sqlite.org/lang_update.html) syntax. The columns you want to `SET` must not be enclosed in a pair of `( )`.

Comment: @gcxh You are free to upvote and/or accept my answer.